# OpenCV Tiff Wrong Color Values Readout

Tags: c, opencv, rgb, color-space, imread

I have a `16-bit tiff` image with no color profile (camera profile embedded) and I am trying to read its RGB values in `OpenCV`. However, comparing the output values to the values given when the image is opened by `GIMP` for example gives totally different values (`GIMP` being opened with keeping the image's profile option; no profile conversion). I have tried also another image studio software like `CaptureOne` and the result accords with `GIMP` differs from `OpenCV` output.

Not sure if reading and opening the image in `OpenCV` is wrong somehow, in spite of using `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag.

I have as well tried to read the image using `FreeImage` library but still the same result.

Here is a snippet of the code reading pixels' values in `OpenCV`

```c
const float Conv16_8 = 255.f / 65535.f;
cv::Vec3d curVal;
// upperLeft/lowerRight are just some pre-defined corners for the ROI
for (int row = upperLeft.y; row <= lowerRight.y; row++) {
    unsigned char* dataUCPtr = img.data + row * img.step[0];
    unsigned short* dataUSPtr = (unsigned short*)dataUCPtr;

    dataUCPtr += 3 * upperLeft.x;
    dataUSPtr += 3 * upperLeft.x;

    for (int col = upperLeft.x; col <= lowerRight.x; col++) {
        if (/* some check if the pixel is valid */) {
            if (img.depth() == CV_8U) {
                for (int chan = 0; chan < 3; chan++) {
                    curVal[chan] = *dataUCPtr++;
                }

            }
            else if (img.depth() == CV_16U) {
                for (int chan = 0; chan < 3; chan++) {
                    curVal[chan] = (*dataUSPtr++)*Conv16_8;
                }
            }
            avgX += curVal;
        }
        else {
            dataUCPtr += 3;
            dataUSPtr += 3;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the image ([download the image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12sthZQvuR98fsVxI5SUQylI_KzyJKfwX/view?usp=sharing)) I am reading with its RGB readouts in

`CaptureOne Studio` AdobeRGB:

[image: CaptureOne AdobeRGB Readouts]

vs `OpenCV` RGB (A1=white --> F1=Black):

[image: OpenCV RGB]

PS1: I have tried also to change the output color space in `GIMP/CaptureOne` to sRGB but still the difference is almost the same, not any closer to `OpenCV`

PS2: I am reversing `OpenCV imread` channels' order before extracting the RGB values from the image `COLOR_RGB2BGR`

Comment: You say you have a TIF, but have shared a PNG? Please share your actual TIF, maybe using Dropbox or Google Drive. You say your image is 16-bit, but your white is shown as 255 which is 8-bit and your OpenCV values are floating point which is normally 32-bit not 16-bit?

Comment: A link has been added to the source image (tiff 16-bit). and yeah this how the software output is converted 16-bit to 8-bit range [0-255]. For my `OpenCV` output there is a `conv16_8` factor with which the values are being converted to 8-bit range [0-255]. I can provide the actual 16-bit readouts if necessary but I don't see it is the problem

Comment: The TIFF file you have shared is 24-bit, i.e. RGB888.

Comment: oh sorry...I seemed to have mistaken the image. Please check now the link again I've updated it

Comment: Ok, the image you have now shared is 16-bits per channel, so actually 48-bits per pixel - nice camera and lens 

Comment: What is `Conv16_8` please?

Comment: oh thanks. Added to the code `const float Conv16_8 = 255.f / 65535.f;`

Comment: The `Conv16_8` in a essence is doing division with a float multiplication (1.f/255.f). Did you tried to shift `>> 8` or just divide it by integer value, to see if it has any impact?

Comment: Ok, where is `curVal` defined please? Did you realise your code is supposed to be complete and runnable...

Comment: it is just a `cv` vector of doubles... also now in the code, hopefully I didn't forget any other definition. I will review the pasted code once again. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: What are the coordinates of the regions you are testing please?

Comment: well...the algorithm that defines the ROI (namely the center of each color patch in the image) is quite complex and long...maybe I try to provide the end data in array or vector form. I will let you know. But for testing you may use hard-coded coordinates for the grayscale patches that would be the easiest.

Comment: The point of asking you which coordinates you used is to ensure I get the same area as you - not to pick a potentially different area myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, it is all about having, loading and applying the proper ICC profile on the `cv::Mat` data. To do that one must use a color management engine along side `OpenCV` such as `LittleCMS`.

Answer (score 1):

OP said:

> *I have a 16-bit tiff image **with no color profile** (camera profile embedded)*

Well no, your image definitely *has* a color profile, and it should not be ignored. The embedded profile is as important as the numeric values of each pixel. Without a defined profile, the pixel values are somewhat meaningless.

From what I can tell, OpenCV does not linearize gamma by default... except when it does... Regardless, the gamma indicated in the profile is unique:

[image: Phase One Profile]

Now compare that to sRGB:

[image: sRGB Profile]

So the sRGB transformations can't be used.

If you are looking for performance, applying the curve via LUT is usually more efficient than a full-on color management system.

In this case, using a LUT. The following LUT was taken from the color profile, 16bit values, and 256 steps:

```
    // Phase One TRC from color profile

  profileTRC = [0x0000,0x032A,0x0653,0x097A,0x0CA0,0x0FC2,0x12DF,0x15F8,0x190C,0x1C19,0x1F1E,0x221C,0x2510,0x27FB,0x2ADB,0x2DB0,0x3079,0x3334,0x35E2,0x3882,0x3B11,0x3D91,0x4000,0x425D,0x44A8,0x46E3,0x490C,0x4B26,0x4D2F,0x4F29,0x5113,0x52EF,0x54BC,0x567B,0x582D,0x59D1,0x5B68,0x5CF3,0x5E71,0x5FE3,0x614A,0x62A6,0x63F7,0x653E,0x667B,0x67AE,0x68D8,0x69F9,0x6B12,0x6C23,0x6D2C,0x6E2D,0x6F28,0x701C,0x710A,0x71F2,0x72D4,0x73B2,0x748B,0x755F,0x762F,0x76FC,0x77C6,0x788D,0x7951,0x7A13,0x7AD4,0x7B93,0x7C51,0x7D0F,0x7DCC,0x7E8A,0x7F48,0x8007,0x80C8,0x8189,0x824C,0x8310,0x83D5,0x849B,0x8562,0x862B,0x86F4,0x87BF,0x888A,0x8956,0x8A23,0x8AF2,0x8BC0,0x8C90,0x8D61,0x8E32,0x8F04,0x8FD7,0x90AA,0x917E,0x9252,0x9328,0x93FD,0x94D3,0x95AA,0x9681,0x9758,0x9830,0x9908,0x99E1,0x9ABA,0x9B93,0x9C6C,0x9D45,0x9E1F,0x9EF9,0x9FD3,0xA0AD,0xA187,0xA260,0xA33A,0xA414,0xA4EE,0xA5C8,0xA6A1,0xA77B,0xA854,0xA92D,0xAA05,0xAADD,0xABB5,0xAC8D,0xAD64,0xAE3B,0xAF11,0xAFE7,0xB0BC,0xB191,0xB265,0xB339,0xB40C,0xB4DE,0xB5B0,0xB680,0xB750,0xB820,0xB8EE,0xB9BC,0xBA88,0xBB54,0xBC1F,0xBCE9,0xBDB1,0xBE79,0xBF40,0xC005,0xC0CA,0xC18D,0xC24F,0xC310,0xC3D0,0xC48F,0xC54D,0xC609,0xC6C5,0xC780,0xC839,0xC8F2,0xC9A9,0xCA60,0xCB16,0xCBCA,0xCC7E,0xCD31,0xCDE2,0xCE93,0xCF43,0xCFF2,0xD0A0,0xD14D,0xD1FA,0xD2A5,0xD350,0xD3FA,0xD4A3,0xD54B,0xD5F2,0xD699,0xD73E,0xD7E3,0xD887,0xD92B,0xD9CE,0xDA6F,0xDB11,0xDBB1,0xDC51,0xDCF0,0xDD8F,0xDE2C,0xDEC9,0xDF66,0xE002,0xE09D,0xE138,0xE1D2,0xE26B,0xE304,0xE39C,0xE434,0xE4CB,0xE562,0xE5F8,0xE68D,0xE722,0xE7B7,0xE84B,0xE8DF,0xE972,0xEA04,0xEA97,0xEB29,0xEBBA,0xEC4B,0xECDC,0xED6C,0xEDFC,0xEE8B,0xEF1A,0xEFA9,0xF038,0xF0C6,0xF154,0xF1E1,0xF26F,0xF2FC,0xF388,0xF415,0xF4A1,0xF52D,0xF5B9,0xF645,0xF6D0,0xF75B,0xF7E6,0xF871,0xF8FC,0xF987,0xFA11,0xFA9B,0xFB26,0xFBB0,0xFC3A,0xFCC4,0xFD4E,0xFDD7,0xFE61,0xFEEB,0xFF75,0xFFFF]
```

If a matching array of the linearized values was needed, it would be

```
   [0x0000,0x0101,0x0202,0x0303,0x0404....
```

But such an array is not neded for most uses, as the index value of the PhaseOne TRC array directly relates to the linear value.

I.e. `phaseOneTRC[0x80]` is `0xAD64`
and the linear value is `0x80 * 0x101`.